# How can I use the fact that $6=2\cdot 3=(\sqrt{10}-2)(\sqrt{10}+2)$ to prove $Z[\sqrt{10}]$ is not a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

How can I use the fact that $6=2\cdot 3=(\sqrt{10}-2)(\sqrt{10}+2)$ to prove $Z[\sqrt{10}]$ is not  a UFD?

They are different ways of factoring 6 into irreducibles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**:

That's exactly the idea, but showing that these elements are irreducible must be proven. It must also be proven that for example $2$ is not equal to $u(\sqrt{10}-2)$ for some unit $u \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}].$ So you should also determine the units of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$.

Comment: DId you mean $10$ or $-10$?

Comment: why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt(-10)]$ ?

Comment: Edited. Thanks both.

Comment: thanks! :) i got it

Comment: Describing the units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{10}\,]$ is not necessary: all you need do (after verifying irreducibility of all four quantities here) is observe that neither $(\sqrt{10}-2)/2$ nor $(\sqrt{10}-2)/3$ is in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{10}\,]$, in particular not a unit.